# Seleccionar el ultimo item agregado en un ng-repeat AngularJs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Como puedo seleccionar el ultimo **item** agregado desde un **boton** a una lista que tengo con un `ng-repeat`, tengo el siguiente código:

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
  $scope.numbers.push(i);
 }
 
 $scope.add = function(number) {
   $scope.numbers.push(number);
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.13"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  {{referenceNumber}}
    <select ng-model="referenceNumber">
      <option ng-selected="!referenceNumber">Default</option>
   <option ng-repeat="number in numbers track by $index" ng-value="number">{{number}}</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" ng-click="add('10')">Add</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Te refieres a que el ultimo item quede por defecto en el select?

Comment: @PauloUrbanoRivera si

Comment: que tal si asignas `referenceNumber  = $scope.numbers.length -1`

Comment: la idea de trabajar con los ng-values es que le puedes asignar valores al mismo y este se ve reflejado en el HTML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deberías setear tu **scope.referenceNumber** en el `controller` de la siguiente forma

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
app.controller('ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = [];
  $scope.referenceNumber = {}
    
  for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
     $scope.numbers.push(i);
  }  
  
  $scope.add = number => {
     $scope.numbers.push(number)
     refresh()
}
  
const refresh = () => {
   //console.log(JSON.stringify($scope.numbers))
   $scope.referenceNumber = parseInt($scope.numbers.length - 1)
}  
refresh()
 }])
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="container" ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{referenceNumber}}
    <select ng-options="number for number in numbers" ng-model="referenceNumber"></select>
        <button type="button" ng-click="add(10)">Add</button>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
```

En la línea `$scope.referenceNumber = $scope.numbers.length-1` indicas que deseas asignar el último elemento del arreglo de *$scope.numbers* mediante su propiedad *length - 1*

La idea de asignar la variable **referenceNumber** es porque es el `scope` asignado en el `ng-model`; de esta forma se setea de forma inmediata el valor y *se evita que al realizar alguna operación la variable NO tenga un valor por defecto*

Además adapte tu `select` para que use la funcionalidad del **[ng-options](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions)** propio de angularjs

En cuanto a actualizar el valor al apretar el botón **ADD**, tienes un error al pasar el número '10', ya que lo estas *entregando como un string cuando en realidad tu arreglo es de números*; eso lo puedes solucionar sacando las comillas en tu add('10') o convirtiendo a número el valor en el push

Comment: pero cuando le doy al boton add en el select no queda seleccionado el valor agregado osea el numero 10

Comment: Ese es otro tema, me limite sólo a responder lo que preguntaste =/. Déjame revisar

Comment: Ya la he editado, la idea es que seleccione el ultimo option cuando se van agregando desde un boton

Comment: Deberías agregar `$scope.referenceNumber = number` después del `push` en tu función **add**

Comment: @zerokira editada!

Comment: muchas gracias tu respuesta me ha servido mucho

Answer (score 1):

Debes usar la directiva `ng-selected` para generar la condición de selección de un item, la cual en este caso es simplemente el último item el cual capturas usando `$last`

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.numbers = [];
 for(var i = 0; i < 10; ++i){
  $scope.numbers.push(i);
 }
 
 $scope.add = function(number) {
   $scope.numbers.push(number);
 }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="http://code.angularjs.org/1.2.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.13"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <pre>referenceNumber : {{referenceNumber}}</pre>
    <select ng-model="referenceNumber">
      <option ng-selected="!referenceNumber">Default</option>
   <option ng-repeat="number in numbers track by $index" ng-value="number" ng-selected="{{ $last }}">{{number}}</option>
  </select>
  <button type="button" ng-click="add('10')">Add</button>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: no es una buena practica hacer `ng-value="{{ number }}" ` ya que el ngvalue espera una variable, de esa forma estas imprimiendo el valor

Comment: @JackNavaRow uy tienes toda la razón me equivoqué de lugar al poner los {{}}, no lo había visto

Comment: en el selected lo muestra seleccionado pero la variable `referenceNumber` no esta asignada, por ello esta opcion yo no la recomiendo